# Laravel 7 : Why I am Getting Only First Array? I want to Fetch All Category ID data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am getting a issue while fetching array data in Laravel 7 here is my code
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZbg6.png

and the result is : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByKaV.png

It is fetching only one array data. I don't know where i am missing.

If anybody know the error, please help me to solve this issue.

Below is my code ======================================

```
  $cat_id = $category->id;
   
$location = null;        

 $sites = \DB::select( 'SELECT id FROM sites WHERE category_id = ?', [ $category->id ]);


    $all = [  ];

            foreach( $sites as $s ) {
                $all[  ] = $s->id;
            }

            $sites = $all;
            
  $all_cat_id = implode(',', array_map('intval', $sites));
            
//   echo "<pre>";
//             print($all_cat_id);
//             die();            

       
$sites = Sites::withCount('reviews')->orderBy('reviews_count', 'desc')->where('id', [$all_cat_id])->paginate(10);

    
    return view('browse-category', [ 'activeNav' => 'home', 
    'reviews' => $reviews, 
    'sites' => $sites, 
    'category' => $category, 
    'all_categories' => $all_categories, 
    'location' => $location 
    ]);
```

Comment: First of all, never use Images, instead please use your actual code when you are asking questions.

& it seems you should use whereIn instead of where

Comment: What is the reason of getting all ids of sites matching category_id first, and then to again retrieve all sites that matching those ids? Isn't it not enough, to get all `sites` where the `category_id` matches `$category->id`. Like only : 
`$sites = Sites::withCount('reviews')->where('category_id', $category->id)->orderBy('reviews_count', 'desc')->paginate(10);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$sites = Sites::withCount('reviews')->orderBy('reviews_count', 'desc')->whereIn('id', [$all_cat_id])->paginate(10);
```

You need to use `whereIn()` instead of `where()`

whereIn() checks column against array.

Comment: Still the Result is Same. I already tested this one. Thank you for you comment

Comment: @Rahi what do you have in `$all_cat_id` ? those id's exists in `Sites` ? have you check manually ?

Comment: The problem is actually code working in localhost but not in Cpanel when the data exceed 1000+ in specific category.. it display blank array in that category... i don't know where is the issue